# Proof that if $a$ and $b$ must be coprime, $a$ has an inverse $\pmod{b}$

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

Assume there exists some integer $x$ for which $ax \equiv 1\pmod{b}$; $a \in \mathbb{Z}, b \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\} $
\begin{align*}
ax &\equiv 1\pmod{b}\\
ax&=qb+1 &&\text{ for some integer $q$ by the division algorithm}\\
\gcd(&qb,qb+1)=1 &&\text{ since any pair of consecutive integers are coprime}\\
\gcd(&qb,ax)=1 &&\text{ by substitution}\\
\gcd(&b,a)=1
\end{align*}
Thus $a$ and $b$ are coprime.  In other words, if there exists some inverse of $a \pmod{b}$, then $a$ and $b$ must be coprime.

---

Is this proof valid?  Are there any improvements I could make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's fine.  For me I just find it more direct to look at $ax+qb=1$ and see that any divisor of $a$ and $b$ divides the LHS, hence divides the RHS, or $1$.

Comment: Hmm that is much more direct, thank you.